# Magento 2 Discount Rule does not show Default Rule Label

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I set up a Cart Price Rule that gives 30% discount. The 30% discount is given to the order, however, it displays "Discount" instead of the Default Rule Label specified.

### Cart Price Rule Setup

The following is details to the Rule I added: 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

### Frontend

Even though the labels were set, it shows Discount in the front end
[image]

### Edit:

With more research I saw that the variable "Discount" is passed to the Knockout JS discount.html template instead of the Discount Description.

`module-sales-rule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="before_grandtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/cart/totals/discount</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2):

Copy

> /public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/template/cart/totals/discount.html

to your theme

> /public_html/app/design/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_SalesRule/view/frontend/web/template/cart/totals/discount.html

and

> /public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/discount.js

to

> /public_html/app/design/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_SalesRule/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/discount.js

Change contents of `discount.html` to:

```
<!-- ko if: isDisplayed() -->
<tr class="totals">
    <th colspan="1" style="" class="mark" scope="row">
        <span class="title" data-bind="text: getDiscountLabel()"></span>
        <span class="discount coupon" data-bind="text: getCouponLabel()"></span>
    </th>
    <td class="amount" data-bind="attr: {'data-th': title}">
        <span><span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Add this function to `discount.js` (for example, put it below the `getCouponLabel` function):

```
getDiscountLabel: function () {
    if (!this.totals()) {
        return null;
    }

    return this.totals()['total_segments'][2]['title'];
},
```

Clear static files and cache.